# How can I set "EUR" as the default currency in simpleCart?

Tags: javascript, simplecart

I'm working on this piece of javascript code in a web page:

```
<script src="http://shopppingcart.googlecode.com/files/simplecart.js"></script>

    simpleCart({
        currency: "EUR",
        language: "greek-el",
        checkout: {
            type: "PayPal",
            email: "you@yours.com"
        }
    });
```

...but it seems that it doesn't work in this way and i can not find the mistake. I want to set `EUR` as the default currency.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Please lookup JavaScript Objects and see how they are structured.

Comment: Open console, there are errors.

Comment: I've just made an update that might help you give me an answer.